# find playlists containing a video on youtube

Tags: youtube, playlist, youtube-channels

I would like to find playlists on youtube that contain the video. e.g. find all playlists that contain video at [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fFIDyFRrdw).

Any youtube search technique/parameter useful for this?

Is it possible to search by author too? e.g. find a playlist containing above video by author `SAS Software`?

Answer (score 17):

With youtube search, use Filter - 'Playlist' and sort by relevance.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Youtube API does not support search for playlists by video.
You can search for playlists, using the title of the video in quotes (").

Unfortunately, very generic titles does not give you the desired results.

Also, keep in mind that if the title contains symbols, you have to exclude them from quotes.

In your example, the title is:

```
Exploration & Prediction with SAS® Visual Statistics
```

This must become like this to search for playlists containing this video:

```
"Exploration" "Prediction with SAS" "Visual Statistics"
```

Example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?type=playlist&part=snippet&maxResults=50&q=%22Exploration%22+%22Prediction+with+SAS%22+%22Visual+Statistics%22&key=
```

(don't forget to add your API key at the end of the URL.

Comment: I tried this and it only returned *MY* two playlists that include the video in question.  According to my analytics there are others in other countries,  I would like to find them and thank them.    That is what I am really after.